# How to use one loading window instance in all activities

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, singleton, loading

First of all, thank you.

I want to make one loading window for all activity. 
Loading window's layout is match_parent/match_parent ConstraintLayout, have one lottieAnimationView(or ProgressBar).

In other words, I want Transparent FullScreen Loading window.
Per Activitiy, add ProgressBar..attach.. I don't think it's a good solution.

So, I tried to use the AlertDialog as a singleton, but when I ran the AsyncTask, I had a problem closing the dialog when the activity's context changed.

How can I use a custom loading window singleton in all my activities?

```
class AlertUtils {
    companion object {
        private var loadingDialog:AlertDialog?=null

        @JvmStatic
        fun showLoadingDialog(activity : Activity, theme: LoadingColorTheme=LoadingColorTheme.COLOR_WHITE_DEFAULT) {
            if (activity.isFinishing)
                return

            loadingDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar).create()
            loadingDialog?.let {
                it.setCancelable(false)
                it.show()

                it.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog_loading_lottie)
                setThemeLoadingDialog(activity, it, theme)
            }
        }

        @JvmStatic
        fun hideLoadingDialog() {
            loadingDialog?.let {_loadingDialog ->
                if (_loadingDialog.isShowing) {
                    _loadingDialog.dismiss()
                }
            }
        }

        private fun setThemeLoadingDialog(activity: Activity, loadingDialog: AlertDialog, theme: LoadingColorTheme) {
            val parentLayout = loadingDialog.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.progress_dialog_loading_lottie_layout)
            val lottieView = loadingDialog.findViewById<LottieAnimationView>(R.id.progress_dialog_lottie_view)

            if (theme === LoadingColorTheme.COLOR_BLACK) {
                parentLayout?.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorBlackAlpha70))
                lottieView?.setAnimation(R.raw.loading_indicator_white)
            } else {
                parentLayout?.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.colorWhiteAlpha80))
                lottieView?.setAnimation(R.raw.loading_indicator_color)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is to create an extension function of your view class. Create a base activity and define two methods there fun View.hideProgressBar() and View.showProgressBar() and handle the scenario there. If the view is visible then only hide it and if the view is invisible/gone show the progress bar. You can also handle the lifecycle methods in your base activity and show/hide the progress bar in your associated activities

Comment: @IshtdeepHora Thank you for answer. As you say, it's a good idea to create a base activity with a progressbar. The dialog seems tricky to hide after some point. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a class which have below method and

```
public static void showDialog4Activity(final Context context, String title, String message) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            @SuppressLint("InflateParams") final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aommoncls_dialogbox, null);
            TextView titileTextView = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tv_titile);
            TextView msgTextView = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);
            Button dialogButtonOKButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            titileTextView.setTypeface(Validations.setTypeface(context));
            msgTextView.setTypeface(Validations.setTypeface(context));
            dialogButtonOKButton.setTypeface(Validations.setTypeface(context));
            msgTextView.setText(message + "");
            titileTextView.setText(title + "");
    //        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    //
    //        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myDialog));
            final Dialog builder = new Dialog(context, R.style.myDialog);
    //        final AlertDialog b = builder.create();
            builder.create();
            //  builder.setTitle("Material Style Dialog");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
    //        builder.setView(dialogView);
            builder.setContentView(dialogView);
            builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            builder.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            builder.show();
    //        final AlertDialog show = builder.show();
            dialogButtonOKButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //  show.dismiss();
                    builder.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
```

And have called like below

```
  CLASSNAME.showDialog4Activity(LoginActivity.this, "","");
```

Here CLASSNAME is the class in which we have defined showDialog4Activity method.

Comment: @apurv thakkar 
Thank you for the answer. My intention is to make the dialog as a loading window (not cancelable) rather than a normal dialog. I wanted to hide the dialog itself after some asynchronous task.